# No data available in table (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I fetched data from my localhost database. However, a "No data available in table" shows up in my datatables. I am having a hard time figuring out what is the problem because I don't get any errors from it. I use the function fetch in my system_model.php to fetch data from the database. Is there any way to find why values from the database are not showing?

## Here is my code for my controller:

```
class SFM_controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    // Load form helper library
    $this->load->helper('form');

    $this->load->helper('url');
    // // Load form validation library
     $this->load->library('form_validation');

    // // Load session library
   $this->load->library('session');

    // Load database
    $this->load->model('system_model');
    }

public function index()
{
    $data = array(
        //'logo' => base_url()."/assets/images/logo/fams-small.png",            
        //'full_name' => $this->session->user_full_name,            
        'fo_supp' => $this->system_model->fetch('fo_supp'),
    );
    $this->load->view('includes/SFM/SFM_Header');
    $this->load->view('includes/SFM/SFM_NavBar');
    $this->load->view('SFM_view',  $data);
    $this->load->view('includes/SFM/SFM_Footer');   
}

function logout()
{
    $this->load->view('includes/Login/Login_Header'); //$data);     
    $this->load->view('Login_view');
    $this->load->view('includes/Login/Login_Footer');
}
```

}

## Here is my code for my Model:

```
 class system_model extends CI_Model
{
    function fetch($table, $where = null, $group_by = null, $order_by = null, $limit = null)
    {
        if($where != null) {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }

        if($group_by != null) {
            $this->db->group_by($group_by);
        }

        if($order_by != null) {
            foreach ($order_by as $key => $value) {
                $this->db->order_by($key, $value);
            }
        }

        if($limit != null) {
            $this->db->limit($limit);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get($table);
        return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->result() : false;            
    }
```

## Here is my code for my View:

```
  <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">

                  <thead>


                   <tr>
                      <th>Supplier Code</th>
                      <th>Address</th>
                      <th>Country</th>
                      <th>Description</th>
                      <th>Telephone Number</th>
                      <th>Fax Number</th>
                      <th>Consolidating Agent</th>
                      <th>Contact Person</th>
                      <th>Actions</th> 
                      <th>Discount 1</th>
                      <th>Discount 2</th>
                      <th>Discount 3</th>
                      <th>Discount 4</th>
                      <th>Discount 5</th>
                      <th>Last Transaction</th>
                      <th>Old Supplier</th>
                    </tr> 
                  </thead>


                  <tbody>
                  <?php if(!empty($fo_supp)): ?>
                  <?php foreach($fo_supp as $supp): ?>

                    <tr>    
                      <td> <?=$supp->supp_code?> </td>
                      <td>   <?=$supp->address." ".$supp->address2?></td>
                      <td><?=$supp->country?></td>
                      <td><?=$supp->description?></td>
                      <td><?=$supp->tel_no?></td>
                      <td><?=$supp->fax_no?></td>
                      <td><?=$supp->contact?></td>
                      <td><?=$supp->cons_agent?></td>


                           <td>$320,800</td>

                      <td><?=$supp->disc1?></td>
                      <td><?=$supp->disc2?></td>
                      <td><?=$supp->disc3?></td>
                      <td><?=$supp->disc4?></td>
                      <td><?=$supp->disc5?></td>

                      <td><?=$supp->last_trans?></td>
                      <td><?=$supp->supp_code2?></td>



                    </tr>




                    <?php endforeach;?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

#### Var dump

[Why is my var dump like this? and not showing values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9baL.png)

Comment: Out of the four view files loaded, which is the one you've shown above?

Comment: The one I posted here is the "SFM_view" file.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing the `$data` array to that view then instead of the `SFM_Header`?

Comment: I already tried doing that. Still no data shows.

Comment: Please update your question then

Comment: @cjpm  Is this view SFM_Header ? And can you see the data if you dump from index method `var_dump( $data['fo_supp'])` ?

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha No, it is the SFM_View file. I'll update my post with the results im getting from the var dump.

Comment: @cjpm  you should add it to the `public function index()` just after the `$data = array(...`  line

Comment: try `var_dump` your `$data` before calling view and put `exit` after that,so you can see your model returning correct value or not

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## SOLVED!

I was passing the data to the wrong controller in which my login submit is located in another controller!

Answer (score 3):

Pass your $data array in the view file instead of header file in controller index function.

```
$this->load->view('SFM_view', $data);
```